# Error when runing jhipster/angular app when using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, jhipster

I'm using a Jhipster/angular app. when I used @angular/material I got this error when I run the application.

[image]

Comment: How did you add the angular/material to your app?

Comment: I tried to run "sudo ng add @angular/material" but I got errorso s
then I added manuelly "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" in angular.json

Comment: Please, try to follow my answer below. I hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your error should be resolved by updating the libraries:

```
npm uninstall @angular/material
npm uninstall @angular/cdk
npm install @angular/material
npm install @angular/cdk
```

Also, you can specify the versions for your `material` and `cdk` packages.

Answer (score 1):

For adding Angular Material to your jhipster project, you can follow these commands:

```
npm install --save @angular/material@10.0.1 @angular/cdk @angular/animations@10.0.2
```

If you are using Angular version 10
you can follow this link with all details : https://medium.com/@cyril.casaucau/how-to-add-angular-material-on-an-jhipster-5-x-app-97c9569c9f97